# How to stop React Ant Design Upload component from posting files automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I have this simple file upload button that I got from antd [ant design documentation](https://ant.design/components/upload/):

```
<Upload>
  <Button
    icon={<UploadOutlined />}
    className="upload-btn"
  >
     Upload a file
  </Button>
</Upload>
```

Every time I upload a file I get this error in the console log:
[image]

I don't want it to make a post request when I upload the file, I have a submit button for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it by returning `false` from `beforeUpload` prop, like this:

```
<Upload beforeUpload={()=> {
    /* update state here */
    return false; }}>
    <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Select File</Button>
</Upload>
```

obviously in this manner you have to define a state, and store files in the state to send it to server manually. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hw2mgn) is an example to implement this logic.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly. Yeah, I defined the state and the submit function and all, that's just an extracted code.

Answer (score 3):

I think it might be late but still. If you don't want your `beforeUpload` API to always return false as it is for validation of files.

You can simply do the following:

```
  <Upload 
    customRequest={({ onSuccess }) => 
      onSuccess("ok")
  }>
     <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Select File</Button>
  </Upload>
```

Providing `customRequest` will stop automatic File upload.

Comment: If you use `customRequest` you'll still see loading icon in File List, to disable loading icon, pass a custom icon renderer function with iconRender prop.
For this reason `beforeUpload` solution was better for me.